# Issue with CI MSSQL connection and the Paginator class

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, codeigniter

I seem to be having an issue with the pagination in codeigniter and my search query.

## Code

```
public function index($page = 0){
    $this->db->select('a.UserID, a.Username, a.UserFullName, a.UserJoined, 
                      (Select Top 1 p.phoneNumber From vwSelectUserPhone p Where p.userID = a.userID) As PhoneNumber, 
                      (Select Top 1 e1.emailAddress From vwSelectUserEmail e1 Where e1.userID = a.userID) As EmailAddress,
                      (Select Top 1 c1.shipCompany From vwSelectOrderAddresses c1 Where c1.userID = a.userID) As UserCompany');
    //$this->db->order_by('UserJoined', 'DESC')
    $this->db->distinct();
    if($_POST){
        $usid = $this->input->post('UserID');
        $ustxt = $this->input->post('TextSearch');
        if(!empty($ustxt) || !empty($usid)){
            if(!empty($usid)){
                $this->db->where('a.UserID', $usid);
            }elseif(!empty($ustxt)){
                $this->session->set_userdata('USrch_Txt', $ustxt);
                $this->db->join('vwSelectUserAddress b', 'b.userID = a.userID', 'left');
                $this->db->join('vwSelectUserEmail c', 'c.userID = a.userID', 'left');
                $this->db->join('vwSelectUserPhone d', 'd.userID = a.userID', 'left');
                $this->db->join('vwSelectUserNotes e', 'e.userID = a.userID', 'left');
                $this->db->join('vwSelectUserVehicle f', 'f.userID = a.userID', 'left');
                $this->db->like('a.Username', $ustxt);
                $orlike = array('a.UserFullName'=>$ustxt,
                                'b.addressStreet1'=>$ustxt,
                                'b.addressStreet2'=>$ustxt,
                                'b.addressCity'=>$ustxt,
                                'b.addressState'=>$ustxt,
                                'b.addressPostalCode'=>$ustxt,
                                'c.emailAddress'=>$ustxt,
                                'd.phoneNumber'=>$ustxt,
                                'e.Note'=>$ustxt,
                                'f.vehMake'=>$ustxt,
                                'f.vehModel'=>$ustxt,
                                'f.vehYear'=>$ustxt,
                                'f.vehTran'=>$ustxt,
                                'f.vehMake'=>$ustxt,
                                'f.vehEngine'=>$ustxt,
                                'f.vehDescription'=>$ustxt,);
                $this->db->or_like($orlike);
            }
        }
    }
    $this->db->order_by('a.UserFullName', 'asc');
    $this->db->limit(12, $page);
    $qry = $this->db->get('vwSelectUser a');
    
    $rs = $qry->result_array();
    $config['base_url'] = '/users';
    $config['per_page'] = 12;
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all('vwSelectUser');
    $config['num_links'] = 5;
    $config['first_link'] = '<span class="fa fa-angle-double-left page_num"></span>';
    $config['last_link'] = '<span class="fa fa-angle-double-right page_num"></span>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<span class="page_num bold">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</span>';
    $config['next_link'] = '<span class="fa fa-angle-right page_num"></span>';
    $config['prev_link'] = '<span class="fa fa-angle-left page_num"></span>';
    $config['uri_segment'] = 2;
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<span class="page_num">';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</span>';
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['rs'] = $rs;
    $data['paging'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $data['current_page'] = $page;
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('pages/users/list', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

As you can see, I have some search parameters in here.  I need to change the `$config['total_rows']` to `$this->db->count_all_results('vwSelectUser')`, however when I do I am faced with the following error:

`Column "vwSelectUser.UserFullName" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

How can I fix this, #1 so it will display the proper pagination links (if there should be any), #2 to get the proper count of the filtered return?

I had though that by doing this: `$config['total_rows'] = ($_POST) ? $this->db->count_all_results('vwSelectUser a') : $this->db->count_all('vwSelectUser a');` that it should do the trick, but I get the error specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there is so much going on in the code I can not tell what you are trying to do.

1 - Run a SQL profiler trace to capture what you are actually sending to the database engine.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx

2 - All the joins can be done right in a TSQL statement.  In fact, a user defined view in the database can simplify the calls in PHP.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx

3 - The error code happens when you are grouping by one set of columns and try to do an order by with a column that is not in the list.

When grouping, either the column has to be in the group by list or an aggregate function on another column.

4 - Like any old style ASP code, comment out sections that do not work.  Get it working and incrementally add back the code.

In short, without the actual code and database, I can only give you the above guide lines.  I think 1 & 2 might simplify the code and give you insight in what is wrong.

Good Luck, J

PS:  Comment out **$this->db->order_by('a.UserFullName', 'asc');** and see if the calculation works.  A separate call to the database can figure out the total and might not cause this error.  However, a view might definitely clean up the code.

Comment: It does work after commenting it out... and actually I found a work-around/fix for it.  If I wrap the query (minus the order) in `start_cache/stop_cache` and then put the `count_all_results` after it, I get it to work properly.